# How to convert a PNG file in to a matrix of pixels?

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, png

I want to convert a PNG file into matrix of pixels. I tried

```
I = imread('d:\image.png');
```

In matlab and I am getting 3 separate matrices ( `R` matrix, `G` matrix, `B` matrix).
I want a single RBG matrix representing the image pixel data.

Comment: what is the size of `I`?

Comment: Maybe you're looking to convert from RGB to an indexed image: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html?refresh=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different ways to represent an image. Go directly to **option3** for a quick answer, but I will also explain in option1 and 2 how the image is represented:

To give an example on a very small sample I will use a very simple image. A blue-*ish* bullet point: [image: bullet]

The actual image used is a downsized version (5x5px) of the bullet point shown above. You can find it here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZdur.png

### option1

If you read that with your command:

```
>> I = imread('icon-bullet_5x5.png')
I(:,:,1) =
    0    0    0    0    0
    0   15   53   26    0
    0   41   89   59    1
    0   16   36   23    1
    0    0    2    0    0
I(:,:,2) =
    0    0    0    0    0
    0   31  103   54    0
    0   96  187  130    4
    0   46  110   69    2
    0    0    4    0    0
I(:,:,3) =
    0    0    0    0    0
    0   56  163   91    0
    0  167  255  216   13
    0   91  212  133    4
    0    0   12    0    0
```

You obtain a 3D matrix of `uint8` (8 bit unsigned integers). Each "slice" of the matrix is the proportion of Red, Blue and Green (on a scale [0 255]). You can vaguely recognize that the value are positioned in the matrix as on the image (some colours in the centre and nothing on the periphery.

This can be viewed as a "single RGB" matrix as you were asking (as discussed with Ander in the comments of his answer, Matlab handle that very well and it is quite convenient).

---

### option2

Another way proposed here was to convert that to indices to a colormap. If you do:

```
>> [X,map] = rgb2ind(I,8)
X =
    0    0    0    0    0
    0    2    6    7    0
    0    6    5    3    0
    0    7    4    1    0
    0    0    0    0    0
map =
                         0                         0       0.00392156862745098
        0.0901960784313725         0.270588235294118          0.52156862745098
        0.0588235294117647          0.12156862745098         0.219607843137255
         0.231372549019608         0.509803921568627         0.847058823529412
         0.141176470588235         0.431372549019608         0.831372549019608
         0.349019607843137         0.733333333333333                         1
         0.184313725490196         0.388235294117647         0.647058823529412
        0.0823529411764706         0.196078431372549         0.356862745098039
```

This represent the same image. The `map` variable contains a list of 8 RGB triplets defining 8 different colors (I chose only 8 colors to not overload the example, but the map could define a lot more colors of course)

The values in `X` are positioned as in the image, and represent the "line number" in the `map`. The line number in this case starts at 0.
For example the pixel at position `X(2,2)` (x=2,y=2 from left, from top) has the value `2`, so the colour for this pixel is defined by the 3rd line in the map => `R/G/B = 0.0588235294117647, 0.12156862745098, 0.219607843137255`.

Careful, here the scale for each colour goes from `0` to `1` (instead of [0 255]), but the interpretation is the same.

---

### option3

However, for your application were you have to communicate with a chip, you will not benefit of Matlab matrix handling and you have to "serialize" it. In memory, there is no concept of 2D, 3D or even higher order. The memory is only 1D, a long succession of addresses. It is only the use of pointers and handlers which gives us the impression of more dimension for a more convenient way to handle these data.

To send that to your chip, you do not need a "single matrix" of RGB values but a single *vector* (a single column or line). A serial succession of pixel information, and a convention defining the relationship between their order in the vector and their position in the matrix (for example as Matlab will lay them out, *from top to bottom*, *from left to right*)

A common way (but definitely not the only way) to represent pixel colours in a serial way is to express them as series of 24 bits values. Each 24 bit value is actually composed of 3 concatenated bytes (8 bits unsigned integer) representing `R / G / B`. Since 24 bits integers are not so human readable to represent colours, this is often represented in hexadecimal format (which is also very handy when you deal directly with microchips).

Matlab offer tools to help you convert easily.

```
RGBhex = [ dec2hex(I(:,:,1)) dec2hex(I(:,:,2)) dec2hex(I(:,:,3)) ]  ;
>> RGBhex
RGBhex =
000000
000000
000000
000000
000000
000000
0F1F38
2960A7
102E5B
000000
000000
3567A3
... // and so on
```

In this representation, the 7th pixel with value `0F1F38` has `Red=0F=15`, `Green=1F=31`, `Blue=0F=56`.
If you count the pixels starting from the top left and column wise, his position in the image is the same than the pixel we took as example above x=2,y=2 (from left, from top)

*note: some format also includes the "transparency" of each pixel in an `Alpha channel`. In this case it is usually concatenated with the RGB triplets and each pixel becomes a 32 bits (4 bytes) value `Alpha / R / G / B`. I did not include that here to keep things simple.*

---

Just as a verification, you can notice that the value are the same than in example 1 (which showed `15/31/56` for the pixel at this position).

A quick conversion also shows that this is the same RGB value than in example 2:

```
>> uint8([[0.0588235294117647, 0.12156862745098, 0.219607843137255]]*256)
ans =
   15   31   56
```

---

If you do not want to handle hexadecimal value and prefer arrays of byte, you can also simply `reshape` the original matrix:

```
>> RGBuint = reshape( I , [] , 3 )
RGBuint =
    0    0    0
    0    0    0
    0    0    0
    0    0    0
    0    0    0
    0    0    0
   15   31   56
   41   96  167
   16   46   91
    0    0    0
    ... // and so on
```

This gives you an array of integers (`uint8`). The position of each pixel is given with the same rule than in the hexadecimal example above. Depending if your chip handle 8/16 or 32 bits communication you can send the bytes one by one or concatenate them to send them in packets.

Comment: Your third option is what I was looking for. Because I think in memory (hardware) pixels are stored in this manner. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 3):

As no-one seems to have been able to do what you want in Matlab, I will show you how to do it with ImageMagick so you can at least get on with what you are trying to do.

First, create a PNG image that is 8x4 pixels with the RGB components of each pixel set to R=00hex, G=44hex, B=55hex so that we have something to play with.

```
convert -size 8x4 xc:"#004455" image.png
```

Check it looks right, with `identify`

```
identify image.png 
image.png PNG 8x4 8x4+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2c 276B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Now, separate the channels of the image into RGB, and swap channels 1 and 2, i.e. swap the Green and Blue channels leaving the Red (channel 0) as is, then recombine the separated channels and write as a raw binary file

```
convert image.png -separate -swap 1,2 -combine RGB:out.raw
```

Now look at the file contents, with `xxd` grouping into threes:

```
xxd -g3 -c12 out.raw
0000000: 005544 005544 005544 005544  .UD.UD.UD.UD
000000c: 005544 005544 005544 005544  .UD.UD.UD.UD
0000018: 005544 005544 005544 005544  .UD.UD.UD.UD
0000024: 005544 005544 005544 005544  .UD.UD.UD.UD
0000030: 005544 005544 005544 005544  .UD.UD.UD.UD
000003c: 005544 005544 005544 005544  .UD.UD.UD.UD
0000048: 005544 005544 005544 005544  .UD.UD.UD.UD
0000054: 005544 005544 005544 005544  .UD.UD.UD.UD
```

You can hopefully see the file contains 4 rows of 8 pixels, each with RBG #005544

Or, if you prefer it as text:

```
convert image.png -separate -swap 1,2 -combine out.txt

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 8,4,255,srgb
0,0: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
1,0: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
2,0: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
3,0: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
4,0: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
5,0: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
6,0: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
7,0: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
0,1: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
1,1: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
2,1: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
3,1: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
4,1: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
5,1: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
6,1: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
7,1: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
0,2: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
1,2: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
2,2: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
3,2: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
4,2: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
5,2: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
6,2: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
7,2: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
0,3: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
1,3: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
2,3: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
3,3: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
4,3: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
5,3: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
6,3: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
7,3: (0,85,68)  #005544  srgb(0,85,68)
```

Comment: ImageMagick is new to me. Can you tell me how to create a png file in imagemagick.

Comment: I created one as the first step in my answer above, size 8x4. A 10x10 red image can be made with `convert -size 10x10 xc:red red.png`, or a 640x480 black JPEG as follows `convert -size 640x480 xc:"#000000" black.jpg`

Comment: I got that. My question was ..  where should I put this code? Imagemagick is a software or online tool?

Comment: I tried online and I downloaded some software from internet. But in both I didn't found any editor where this code can be put and compiled.

Comment: You just type it into the Terminal window and press `Enter/Return` - there is nothing to compile.

Comment: thank you. I will try this. If am stuck again please do help me.

Answer (score 2):

How is that you are getting 3 separate matrices?

You should have 1 matrix, of size MxNx3. If you want that 3 to become 1, you are going to loose information most likely. You have several options, depending what you want.

One of them is to convert your RGB image into grayscale, easy to do with `Ig=rgb2gray(I)`.

Another, as @Dan suggested, is to create an indexed image. An indexed image has integers instead of colors, integers that are supposed to be indexes of a dictionary where the real colors are stored. you can do `[Iind,dict]=rgb2ind(I)`. Indexed images allows you, for example, to store a big image with few colors in less memory.

I will leave this here, and If this is not what you are looking for, let me know to update the answer with more info.

Comment: Got some idea from your answer. Thank you. You said matrix is of size MxNx3. Then how it is possible to store this matrix in a memory? Memory is two dimensional right?

Comment: @tollin it is not! you can make any dimensional matrices in Matlab! try it! create a random matrix of 5 dimensions with: `A=rand(3,3,3,3,3)`! Try it.Create it and check its dimensions in the workspace.

Comment: not in the system memory. I am asking with respect to FPGA. So to RAM (2D) I have to port this image data.

Comment: @tollin I am not used to FPGAs sorry, but in computer memory is not like that. A 1D matrix is a pointer to a memory location. A 2D array is an array of pointers to 1D matrices. a 3D matrix is an array of pointers to 2D matrices that are themselves arrays of pointers to 1D matrices... However I believe that you know more than me of electronics! Anyway, in Matlab, you can create any dimensional matrices, and If you are using Matlab's VHDL code generation tools, dont worry, Matlab knows how to handle those kind of things (I believe).